# Clear cart and display message

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to display a message for the user when paypal payment returns successful.I am calling the ClearCart in Cart Controller to remove all the cart items. However, it only clears the cart and does not display the message. The script for paypal onApprove added in the same Index.cshtml view. Here is my code for it.

```
  onApprove: function (data, actions) {
            // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
            return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {

                window.location.href = '@Url.Action("ClearCart","Cart")'; 

                const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');

                // Hide the PayPal buttons by setting display to none
                element.style.display = 'none';

                // Create the success message element
                const successMessage = document.createElement('div');
                successMessage.innerHTML = '<p style="color: blue; text-align: left;">Thank you ' + details.payer.name.given_name + ' for your payment!</p>';

                // Replace the PayPal buttons with the success message element
                element.parentNode.replaceChild(successMessage, element);

            });
        }
```

This is my ClearCart function

```
 public IActionResult ClearCart()
        {
            SaveCartItems(new List<CartItem>());
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I want the paypal buttons to be hidden and replaced by a transaction message when the user successfully completes payment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`actions.order.create` and `actions.order.capture` are deprecated and should not be used for any new integration. Follow the [standard integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), which shows sample code to create and capture orders in a backend. The sample's two routes are in node.js but they can of course be implemented from any normal server-side environment including .NET

In your onApprove code you are redirecting to the URL given by `@Url.Action("ClearCart","Cart")` before anything else happens, which does not make sense. The code after that JS redirect simply won't execute, as the page has already changed.

Since your `ClearCart` appears to be a backend function, simply call it *within* the capture route you are going to replace actions.order.capture with . I.e. have your server capture route do everything the server needs to do before forwarding a JSON response on to the caller.

In the frontend onApprove function, when handling that JSON response, your code to show a success message appears as though it will work, however you should add handling to check if the capture failed before showing your success message.  The best example of such a complete onApprove function is in [this PayPal demo code](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server), which will also restart the checkout if the error is recoverable.